# Unable to connect to MySQL cluster database

Tags: mysql, cluster, mysql-cluster

I am unable to connect to mysql cluster database after starting my management node, data node, mysql node. I made the necessary changes by adding the loadbalance in the dbURL. But I am not able to access the connection. The mysqld port is 1186. Please assist.

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://localhost/bank";
String dbDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private Connection dbCon;
public boolean connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName(dbDriver);

        // login credentials to your MySQL server
        dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, "root", ""); 
        return true;
    }
```

The error I am getting when I try to log in is:

> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure

How do I test MySQL cluster database? I managed to login using the following in command prompt. Please assist.

> mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P5000 -u root

Comment: I managed to connect. Require to change the port.

Comment: Please provide an answer (rather than a comment) and when you can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Required to change the port to resolve the issue.

> String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://localhost:3306/bank";